# Oberbegriff für if, goto, while usw. aus Programmiersprachen

Tags: single-word-request, technical-terminology

Welchen Oberbegriff könnte man *if, goto, while, for* etc. aus Programmiersprachen geben? Also was sind diese »Wörter« eigentlich?

Befehle? Schlagwörter?

Ich brauche es für folgenden Satz:

> Die Unix-Kommandos `goto` und `if` sind mit den ??? der Programmiersprache C vergleichbar.

Comment: Sicher ist die Definition eines „Unix-Kommandos“ nicht ganz klar, aber man sollte bemerken, dass Kontrollstrukturen Sache der Shell sind, und kurzes Googeln sagt mir, dass csh ein `goto` hat, sh aber nicht.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es handelt sich dabei um **Kontrollstrukturen** *(control structures),* welche eine spezielle Untergruppe von **Anweisungen** *(statements)* darstellen.

Übrigens: **Befehl** *(command)* und **Instruktion** *(instruction)* sind nur Synonyme für **Anweisungen** (manchmal wird damit jedoch auch Bezug auf Maschinenbefehle genommen).

Bleiben wir penibel genau, gibt es auch keine UNIX-Kommandos, sondern nur UNIX-Anweisungen. Die zwei genannten (`goto` und `if`) sind jedoch zugleich selbst Kontrollstrukturen. Sie sind in ihrem Verhalten nicht nur vergleichbar mit den Kontrollstrukturen von C, nein, aus reiner Benutzersicht sind sie äquivalent. Natürlich ist die Implementierung unterschiedlich, auch die Funktionsweise mag anders sein, aber die Intention in dem, was sie machen sollen, ist identisch.

#### Referenzen

- [Wikipedia: Kontrollstruktur](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontrollstruktur)

Answer (score 4):

Schlüsselwörter oder reservierte Wörter.

Comment: Jedes Wort wird zum Schlüsselwort oder zum reservierten Wort in dem Moment wo es verwendet wurde. Deshalb wurden auch `namespaces` erfunden, weil das immer ein Problem darstellt in der Programmierung. In diesem Zusammenhang wären also beide Oberbegriffe noch schwammiger wie **Befehl** oder **Anweisung**.

Comment: Das ist nicht richtig. C oder Java beispielsweise definieren Schlüsselwörter wie `struct` oder `class`, da machst Du auch mit Namespaces nix dran.

Comment: Weil sie zuvor definiert wurden, diese Wörter sind nicht einfach *magisch vergeben*. Ob die Wörter in einem Namespace verwendet werden dürfen oder nicht hängt von der jeweiligen Programmsprache und ihrer Einschränkungen durch Parser, Lexer, Compiler, etc. ab. Aber ja, es gibt Programmiersprachen mit **reservierten (Schlüssel)Wörtern** die in keinem anderen Kontext vorkommen dürfen (z. B. [PHP: List of Keywords](https://php.net/manual/reserved.php)).

Comment: @Fleshgrinder WP gibt recht: "Der Begriff Schlüsselwort [..] oder reserviertes Wort bezeichnet in einer Programmiersprache ein Wort, dass [..] nicht als Name von Variablen oder Funktionen verwendet werden darf." Es wir hier also explizit von Variablen unterschieden. Die Definition der Schlüsselworte erfolgt in der Definition der Sprache selbst und ist damit aus Sicht des Programm-Codes durchaus *magisch*

Comment: Die Definition der Schlüsselworte erfolgt jedoch oft auch in der Programmiersprache selbst, deshalb sage ich, dass es nicht *magisch* ist. Ich sage ja nicht, dass `if` kein Schlüsselwort ist und/oder kein reserviertes Wort ist (ist es), jedoch, dass der Oberbegriff zu schwammig ist weil noch viele weitere Wörter reserviert sind (z. B. `class`) und deshalb **Kontrollstrukturen** für die vom OP genannten Anweisungen (die zugleich Schlüsselwörter sind) treffender sind. Das mit den Namensräumen stimmt vlt. nicht für `if`, jedoch z. B. für die Klasse `String`. ;)

Comment: Nur um das nochmals klarzustellen: **alle Antworten die hier gegeben wurden sind korrekt!** Ich wollte im Kommentar nur anmerken, dass *Schlüsselwörter*, *reservierte Wörter*, *Befehle* und *Anweisungen* schwammiger sind, da sie für viel mehr stehen als *Kontrollstrukturen* und keinesfalls, dass jemand eine schlechte oder unwahre Antwort gegeben hat.